# android nested object parceling

Tags: android, parcel

**how can we parcel nested object in an intent?**. 
For example 
lets say there is an object A which contain one string variable and one another object B. now B contain object C . C contain a list of string. so how i can parcel object A in an intent.
 any help on this will be appreciated.
 thanks in advance.

**Implementation:**

```
public static class A 
{
    private B  ObjectB;
}

public static class B 
{
    private String type;
    private List<C> C;
}

public static class C 
{
    private List<D> D;
}

public static class D 
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email;
}
```

how to write parcelable for class C.
i am using

```
dest.writeParceable(ObjectC,flag)
```

For reading:

```
in.readParcelable(C.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement parcelable for object B and then implement parcelable for object A. I have never done this but the above should work.

**Edit**

See the code snippets below which illustrates how to implement parcelable for Class C.

1. First implement parcelable for Class D like so:

   ```
   dest.writeString(id); 
   dest.writeString(name);  
   dest.writeString(address);  
   dest.writeString(email);

   id = in.readString();  
   name = in.readString();  
   address = in.readString();  
   email = in.readString();
   ```
2. Then implement parcelable for Class C as follows:

   ```
   dest.writeList(D);

   in.readList(D,this.getClass().getClassLoader());
   ```

This is untested code as I have never implemented nested parceling but worth a try. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks mandel.it should work . but i dont know how to implement parcelable for object B. what should we write in writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) and readFromParcel method when we implement parcelable for Object B.

Comment: You will need to add code like so: `dest.writeString(.);` in writeToParce(.) and like so: `testString = in.readString();` in readFromParcel(.). Specifics will depend on the classes involved.

Comment: No Mandel, it will not work for object. B is a collection of custom objects. writeString will work for string only.

Comment: I just gave an example. Show me the three classes and I will be more specific.

Comment: public static class DiagnosticHelp {
   private List<Categories> categories;

Comment: and if class A would be like this:<br/>public static class A {
private B &lt;B&gt; objectB;<br/>
}<br/>then how will we implement parcel for b.

Comment: how to write parcelable for class A?

Answer (score 0):

One way I have seen this done is using serializeable

eg.

if you have a variable:

```
Date createdAt;
```

Then in `writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)` you can write:

```
out.writeSerializable(createdAt);
```

To read the value back yoy would use:

```
createdAt = (Date) in.readSerializable();
```

That being said though Parcelable was specifically created because Java serialization was considered too slow. So while this works it is not a good idea to use for larger pieces of data.